# Forward proxy user authentication does not work

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, authentication, forwarding, configuration

I have got a simple forward proxy that needs to have user authentication and a whitelist of IP-adresses. I have created the vhost below:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8888>
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx
   Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx
   Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx
   Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx

   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Password Required for Proxy"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.proxyhtpasswd
   Require user
</Proxy>
```

The proxy itself works fine, but the user authentication and allowing IP's however does not. I changed the config 10 times and even with only the Auth block in there it still works without having to use a (valid) user/password or having the correct IP-adress.

I also tried to configure this through a normal VirtualHost config and still no success:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8888>
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
    SSLProxyEngine On

    <Location />
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx
        Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx
        Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx
        Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx

        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider file
        AuthName "Password Required for Proxy"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.proxyhtpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by combining the Proxy directive within the VirtualHost directive.

```
<VirtualHost xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8888>
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
    SSLProxyEngine On

    <Proxy *>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx
        Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx
        Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx
        Allow from xx.xxx.xx.xxx

        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider file
        AuthName "Password Required for Proxy"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.proxyhtpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Proxy>

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/proxy-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is either

```
Require valid-user
```

or

```
Require user [theusername]
```

but not

```
Require user
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#require

Comment: Hey Martin, that was probably a typo of a change I did before, strange that it produces no warning or error from Apache. I have to wait for confirmation of the customer to restart Apache and to double check if this working.

Comment: Hey Martin, sadly it still does not work. I still can connect without username/password. I also noticed that the IP allows are not working (I also use a separate firewall, so that is why I haven't noticed it before).

Comment: I suspect that the configuration file is never read by apache, add an obviously wrong directive between the <Proxy> markups and check in the logs if apache detects it.

Comment: I would suspect the same but if I place something bad in the config and I issue an Apache config test, it shows that it fails because of that bad piece of code I added.

Comment: There are also no entries in the Apache error log that relates to the Proxy.

Comment: In that case, I would say that Apache never matches the host/port set here: "<Proxy xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8888>". According to the documentation, the parameter of this control block must be a wildcard or the URL of a request: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxy.

Comment: I tried the wildcard, same result.

Comment: There is nothing more I can do for you, I am affraid.

Comment: Ah that's ok, thanks anyways for the time! I will look at the Apache version and see if there are any bugs documented around this.